# Measures of dissimilarity (distance) between character vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a seemingly easy question which however is troubling me a bit.

I have couples of vectors made up of nominal attributes. They can be of different length and sometimes some of the attributes in one might not be included in the other. See `a` and `b` as two potential examples.

```
               a
1  mathematician
2       engineer
3  mathematician
4  mathematician
5  mathematician
6       engineer
7  mathematician
8  mathematician
9  mathematician
10 mathematician
11 mathematician
12      engineer
13 mathematician
14 mathematician
15      engineer

               b
1      physicist
2        surgeon
3      physicist
4        surgeon
5      physicist
6      physicist
7        surgeon
8        surgeon
9      physicist
10     physicist
11 mathematician
```

Do you have in mind a measure (an index) that could summarize the dissimilarity between them? The type of measure I am looking for is something like the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), but for qualitative vectors.

One option I thought of is to actually compute the Euclidean distance among the categorical vectors earlier transformed into frequency vectors. In this way, they would become quantitative and would be of the same length. But my question is, do you find this a sound approach?

More generally, is there a R package that tackles these type of distances? Can you suggest other distances suitable to the case of nominal variables?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate further: what are you going to do with the measure? What have you tried and why what you have tried is not satisfactory?

Comment: @carloscinelli Thank you for your answer. The reason why I am trying to do this is that I need to compare group composition taking into account (controlling for, if you want) the size of the group.

Comment: is `tm::dissimilarity` helpful?

Comment: @TylerRinker very interesting package.

Answer (score 3):

I've only come across the unalikeability coefficient.

http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v15n2/kader.html

Weird name, intuitive approach, and incredibly simple implementation. For example:

```
> table(a)
a
     engineer mathematician 
            4            11 

> unalike(table(a))
[1] 0.391


> table(b)
b
mathematician     physicist       surgeon 
            1             6             4 
> unalike(table(b))
[1] 0.562
```

It is clear just by eye-balling that `b` would be more dissimilar, and this coefficient gives a more quantitative measure.

There are some examples in the paper which I will calculate for you here:

```
> unalike(3,7)
[1] 0.42
> unalike(5,5)
[1] 0.5
> unalike(1,9)
[1] 0.18
```

The formula in this function is based on the paper I linked you to above:

```
unalike <- function(...) {

  props <- c(...)
  zzz <- 1 - sum(((props) / sum(props)) ** 2)
  zzz <- round(zzz, 3)

  return(zzz)
}
```

Let me know how your thing goes since this is a small side project for me as well.

Comment: But this measures variability **within** a vector, not the distance **between** two vectors, doesn't it?

Comment: In that case, what about a kappa statistic? The only adjustment you'd need to make is to account for the fact that one vector has three categories and the other only has two. For example, think of the vectors as ratings from 1-3 from two different raters. One rater used all three levels but the other only used two.

Comment: @rawr For how simple it is, I find it interesting. Thanks a lot for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a programming question, because you do not know what you want to do yet, so we can't offer a solution. I think the main question here is what are you going to use this measure for, because you can measure dissimilarities in a lot of different ways, some will be good for what you want and some will not.

But trying to answer anyway, there is the `utils::adist` function and there is also a package called [`stringdist`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/) (these are the ones I have used before). But it seems that they are not quite what you want, based on your question, because they will measure the distance for each character string, and not for the whole matrix. But you could use them to have some ideas about how to measure the distance between the two vectors. For example, one measure could be how many changes you would have to make in vector a so it turns to vector b.

Comment: I am continuing from above. You're right, this is not a strictly programming question and it's generic. I thought it was useful to ask it here because, as there are functions and packages made for computing distances between numeric vectors, it could be the case that there were something also for nominal attributes. But probably not... Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: Yeah, try to be more specific, but in the meantime leave the question here for a while, maybe someone will come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for keeping this open.

One option, which appears to have become available after this discussion, is R's qualvar (Gombin) package.  The package provides functions for each of Wilcox's (1967, 1973) Indices of Qualitative Variation.  Included with the package is a useful vignette summarizing implementation and results.  I have found in limited experience that index selection requires some brute-force testing with actual and simulated data.